# Two Times str_replace

Tags: php, api

I'm really hungout to solve this problem.
How can I use str_replace twice for making something like this in command line :

> /send_message user_id message

Note : 
`$text` = (text in command line)
`$to_id` = (user id)
`$to_text` = (message)

```
$to_id = str_replace("/st ","",$text);
$to_text = str_replace("/st $to_id ","",$text);
if ($text == "/st $to_id $to_text") {
        apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $to_id ,"text" => "$to_text"));
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... You replace `"/st "` and `"/st $to_id "` in `$text` by nothing. Why?

Comment: KIKO Software i'm confused too , i'm really don't know i can't thinking anyway :-D

Comment: What is `$text` starting out as?

Comment: Ok, take a break, drink a cup of coffee, and then read the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: chris85 its https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples/hellobot , $text is message proccess function

Comment: I mean what is it literally in your test case `var_dump($text);`. You might be able to use a regex and pull all the information with 1 call. Is it in the same format everytime

Comment: chris85 thanks bro , my problem was solved ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extract user_id and message, right? Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string on the space character.

```
$v = explode(' ', $text, 3);
$to_id = $v[1];
$to_text = $v[2];
```